# have a function to disable close confirmation on terms. work on all terms but shell?

Tags: term

so i have this function i found on the interent

```
   (defun set-no-process-query-on-exit ()
 (let ((proc (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
   (when (processp proc)
     (set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil))))
```

(add-hook 'term-exec-hook 'set-no-process-query-on-exit)

it works great by disabling confirmation when you close a terminal. it works on multi-term, ansi-term, ehsell but for some bizzaro reason not on shell. any one knows why?

Comment: Please follow site norms.  Do not sign off posts with "thanks" or "best."  Do not sign off with your name or initial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`term-exec-hook` is not called by `shell-mode`. It uses a different approach for running a shell, via `comint` rather than `term-exec`. So you need to add your function to the `shell-mode-hook` to get it applied to `shell-mode`.

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'set-no-process-query-on-exit)
```

Comment: perfect this works now